# Google Charts (JS) - is there a way of using a transparent background on a chart?

Tags: google-visualization

I'm using the [Google Charts API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) to include various graphs on a webapp I'm working on.  I'm using the javascript chart tools (**not** the image chart tools), and am wondering if it's possible to use a transparent background on a chart (e.g. line graph, pie chart, etc.)?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

In the Configuration Options of the chart, specify

```
backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent' }
```

This worked for me in Chrome and Firefox.
It took me some time to [find out](http://groups.google.com/group/google-visualization-api/browse_thread/thread/d09df8bef22f49a2). The [doc page](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart.html#Configuration_Options) says you can only put in HTML color strings and I assumed 'transparent' was not one of them.

Comment: That's indeed a lack of documentation I think. Worked great for me !

Comment: If anyone has found this whilst looking for advice regarding Google **Image** Charts then Image Charts can be made transparent by the background colour alpha component being 00. e.g. chf=bg,s,654321**00**

Comment: 2015, march, still working of course. Just a tip : if you want partial transparency, you have to add a class, say "white_transparent" to your chart id, with a background-color:rgba(255,255,255,<less than 1>);
This way, the graph is totally transparent, but an underlying layer is partially transparent.
<div id="my_google_chart" class="white_transparent">

Comment: @MacMac Works for me. You need to put it in var options = { } before you draw the visualization.

Comment: @Tucker Maybe it does not work for Line Charts? I've done both by passing a var or the object of options itself.

Comment: @MacMac I'm actually testing line charts now. I'll let you know if it works there too. I was having a little difficulty putting two different charts on one page.

Comment: @MacMac Okay. I think you're right. I looked into it. When the SVG is drawn, there's an attribute called 'rect', in it fill="white". I've been trying to override this setting somehow, but the API is a little confusing. The solution below by Jonas Littau to replace the element using jScript seems like the best way to go, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 17):

**Setting a transparent background for Google Charts:**

```
// Set chart options
var options = {'title':'Chart Title',
'width':600,
'height':300,
'backgroundColor': 'transparent',
'is3D':true
};
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/portashqipe/kv0tujhv/22/)**

Answer (score 5):

backgroundColor: "00000000" worked for me.

Comment: you have to use the hex basically! `#000000`

Answer (score 4):

If nothing works for you try locating the background rectangle at the end of your drawChart() function and add the fill-opacity attribute.

```
 fill-opacity="0.0"
```

Example:

```
$('#mychart').find('svg rect:eq( 1 )').attr('fill-opacity','0.0');
```

Use the eq:() selector to select the rectangle you want to be transparent.

Answer (score 1):

On the left of the cart there is a dropdown arrow - click that, and go to "cop chart".

When you paste the chart, you can still choose to link it, and it will paste with the background transparent.

Comment: What are you talking about?