# Set background as transparent and responsive for google Line Chart

Tags: javascript, css, charts, responsive, clappr

I want to use Google [linechart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart)
.

This is my project's image 
[image: its a chart for Clappr]

My questions:

1) How can I set the background-color:transparent ??

2) If user click on full page size ( button right ) , the chart will not be 100% width again , how to set it 100% ?

This picture is for second question

[image: responsive]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Charts (JS) - is there a way of using a transparent background on a chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413508/google-charts-js-is-there-a-way-of-using-a-transparent-background-on-a-chart)

Comment: Second part of question is important , which is not answered in other page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only way to reaction about device width (or windows width) and that is  redraw chart.  It is true, but **do not** forget to destroy old chart before redraw new version.

```
 .destroy()
```

This code can remove old chart , after that you can add new chart

```
  // Example from the docs
        var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
   // Destroys a specific chart instance
        myLineChart.destroy();
```

I tested, It is working fine

Answer (score 0):

You can target via CSS the rect attribute of the chart as follows:

```
rect { 
   fill: rgb(0,0,0,0);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kL2vaed4/2/
here is an example where I used a black background so you can see that it works.

Comment: Thank you  and what is your idea for my second question ?

Comment: need some more details, does it have a specific width? it should be styled with width 100% on all media screens. It is hard to guess what is wrong without the actual code, or a jsfiddle/codepen.

Comment: This is source , from Google : https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart


I changed this line :  style="width: 900px; height: 500px"

To : style="width: 100%; height: 50px"




But it does not working fine.

Comment: yes i tried that too, I wonder if you can make jsfiddle with your actual code, you having a video may influence the end resul. The g path that is generated from the svg has a fixed with, and there is a clip path that needs to be modyfied

Comment: maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34064917/how-to-resize-svg-clip-path

Comment: this won't work on other chart types such as Column or Bar. The chart elements will also become transparent. Use standard configuration options instead...

Answer (score 0):

to make the chart's background transparent,
use the following configuration option...

```
backgroundColor: 'transparent',
chartArea: {
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
}
```

to make the chart responsive,
re-draw the chart when the container's size changes,
such as on the window's resize event...

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

see following working snippet,
run the snippet, then click "Full page" to see it change...

note: the container `<div>` has a cyan background

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y'],
    [0, 0],
    [1, 1],
    [2, 2],
    [3, 3],
    [4, 4],
    [5, 5]
  ]);

  var options = {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    chartArea: {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
  window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    chart.draw(data, options);
  });
});
```

```css
#chart_div {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: The chart is inside of a video player , are you sure 'window.addEventListener' is the solution ?

Comment: the only way to resize the chart is to re-draw

Comment: I am using [clappr](https://github.com/clappr/clappr)  and (as i shown in up picture) chart is inside of player...The chart redraw when player is going to full page But when player will return to normal size , Chart does not redraw